# Abstract Algebra book

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, book-recommendation, big-list

Has anyone read the book "Abstract Algebra: An Introduction" by Thomas Hungerford?

I'm in the class Intro to Abstract Algebra, and my professor is, to say the least, not very great at teaching. Great mathematician, but not the best professor.

I was thinking about dropping out and learning it myself, but I was wondering if this book is any good for abstract.

Also, I've never had a proofs class, but I'm picking it up along the way in this class.

Comment: Its one of the greatest texts on Algebra.

Comment: My opinion: it is a very good book for introduction to algebra, especially for someone new to proofs.

Comment: *Also, I've never had a proofs class* -- Perhaps you should stick around in class and form a peer study group where you can learn together. If you never did proof-based math (which is normal in undergrad abstract algebra) then peer support is incredibly helpful and lone-wolfing it is a hard way to go.

Comment: I actually did rather well in my algebra class last summer. I've taken a course on differential geometry and read a book on topology and am currently taking a course in that. I think I did okay in getting into proofs.